# How to apply style to the icon that is being clicked in the array using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to apply style to a specific element which are iterated through `.map`. Currently, when I click on one icon, the style applies to both the icons. I'm expecting toggle behavior on the icons when clicked.

Here's a gist of my code

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

...

{arr.map(({ icon, styledIcon }, index) => (
<Grid key={index} item>
  <IonIcon onClick={()=> setColor(!color)} key={index} icon={color ? icon : styledIcon} >
  </IonIcon>
</Grid>
))}
```

Comment: You will have to identify and have a conditional style application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it down into another component to easily keep track. If you do not want to do that you will need to keep track in your main state using an array of ids or something

```
{arr.map(({ icon, styledIcon }, index) => (
<Grid key={index} item>
    <MyStyledIcon key={index} icon={icon} styledIcon={styledIcon} />
</Grid>
))}


const MyStyledIcon = (props) => {
   const [color, setColor] = React.useState(false);

  <IonIcon onClick={()=> setColor(!color)} icon={color ? props.icon : props.styledIcon} >
  </IonIcon>
}
```

Comment: But curious to know how it worked after splitting the components

Comment: Because you only had 1 color state variable before which all items inside `arr` were using. Moving it to its own component created a color state variable for each item in `arr`